# How do I show that a domain is not simply connected?

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

> Let $U$ be a star-shaped domain in $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that the subset obtained from $U$ by removing a finite number of points is not simply connected.

Usually when we want to show something is simply connected we show that any two curves with fixed endpoints are homotopic by finding a suitable homotopy. However, what can you do if you need to show that the domain is not simply connected? Can we somehow show that there doesn't exist a homotopy?

Comment: You can show that not all loops can be continuously transformed to a single point.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I believe you're right. But I'm really not sure how to do that. Could you help me where to begin?

Comment: For example, if I consider a closed path $\gamma$ in the set and a constant curve $z_0$ in the set. I can generally construct at homotopy by $H(s, t)=s \gamma(t)+(1-s) z_{0}$. 
Can I use this to show somehow that there is a curve that is not homotopic to $z_0$?

Comment: By continuity, when you try to pass a point with a curve, you can't avoid going "through" the point. Maybe a proof by contradiction ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust So if I have removed a point $z_1$ from G, I somehow want to show that there exists a path $\gamma(t)$ and a pair $s,t$ s.t. $H(s,t)=z_1$?

I just really don't know how to approach this in a general case.

Comment: What properties of simply connected domains **do** you know? For instance, the monodromy principle? Cauchy integral theorem? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

If $\Omega$ is simply connected then $Ind_{\gamma} (z)=0$ for any closed path $\gamma $ in $\Omega$ and any point $z $ not in $\Omega$.

If $z$ is one of the points removed from your region there exists a closed disk $\overline {D} (z,r)$ around $z$ cantained in $U$ and the index of $z$ w.r.t. the circle of radius $r$ around $z$ is not zero. Hence, the region is not simply connected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But we have only covered the very basic of simply connected and homotopic. So I'm not familiar with what index means and it's not something covered in my course. Is it possible to show this without using index?

Answer (score 0):

With no technology available whatsoever this is an unreasonable question to ask a new student. It is exactly as difficult as the following theorem.

> The punctured plane $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is not simply connected. In fact, the loop $\gamma_r(\theta) = (r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ is not null-homotopic for any $r>0$.

If you know this fact, you can use it to prove your result.

If not, you are not ready yet to prove the stated claim. This fact is non-trivial and the proof is non-obvious.